# Magento graphql query is returning error "TypeError: Failed to fetch". I dont understand the issue. Can anyone please help

Tags: magento2.3.0

Magento graphql query is returning error "TypeError: Failed to fetch".

I am running it in developer mode.

Endpoint -> http://localhost:81/magento/graphql

Magento version 2.3.3

Windows.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the community!. Did you try with a different tool [e.g. Postman, Altair GraphQl, etc)? You can refer to this article if you are not familiar with how to use postman for Graphql https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/graphql/

Comment: Hi, try to check in network tab of chrome developer tools, there you will get the error message to debug. Also, make sure to switch your Magento instance into developer mode.

Comment: Try this and make sure extra space trouble in graphql. so please avoid.
query {
  cmsPage(
    id:2
  ){
    title
  }
}